# Cannot delete a pycharm project that i cloned from gitlab (Windows 10)

Tags: windows, pycharm, windows-10, gitlab

i deleted this folder entirely through pycharm (when you open the 'pick a directory' option) but the folder wasnt removed (its like an empty inaccessible folder now). 
The Folder is a project i cloned from gitlab.
Since somehow its 'deleted', i can not access it or access the .git folder (where i should have started with deleting after reading multiple pages on the internet).

I can not get access to the folder even though I'm an administrator and i tried deleting using cmd (which won't be any different) and i keep getting 'access denied'. its frustrating! 
does anyone has any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, all it needed was a reboot. I feel pretty bad that I've spent an hour searching for an answer, just to forget the good old "have you tried turning it off and then on again?"